# Ansible playbook not able to pick openshift

Tags: ansible

I installed openshift using pip command `pip install openshift`
but when I run my ansible module it throw error:

> This module requires the OpenShift Python client. Try `pip install openshift`

Comment: Do your ansible module inside a [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)?

Comment: no, i have simple ubuntu 16 machine where ansible 2.6 is installed.